# Get product rank in bestsell products MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Let me tell you an example of the problem I'm having. For example we have table named `order` where we insert all orders and purchases.

Table A (`orders`):

```
+--------------------------+
| CustomerKey | ProductKey |
+--------------------------+
| 306545      | pro1       |
| 597864      | pro3       |
| 784678      | pro2       |
| 905479      | pro3       |
| 306545      | pro1       |
| 348965      | pro3       |
| 784678      | pro3       |
+--------------------------+
```

Now I would like to order and get our best-selling products and for example get pro3 rank in the best-selling products list.

Query output:

```
+-------------------------------+
| id | ProductKey | numberSold  |
+-------------------------------+
| 1  | pro3       | 4           |
| 2  | pro1       | 2           |
| 3  | pro2       | 1           |
+-------------------------------+
```

I wrote this query:

```
select ProductKey, 
count(1) as numberSold
from A group 
by ProductKey 
order by count(1) desc
```

The result is not useful for me. For example, I need to get pro27 ranked in best-selling products (we have 100,000 product!)

```
+-------------------------------------+
| id | ProductKey | numberSold | rank |
+-------------------------------------|
| 1  | pro3       | 4          | 1    |
| 2  | pro1       | 2          | 2    |
| 3  | pro2       | 1          | 3    |
+------------------------------+------+
```

Comment: Wait, why not just `SELECT ProductKey FROM A ORDER BY numberSold DESC LIMIT 1`? You'' get the highest seller in the query.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a derived table to solve this issue. The query will be slow anyways, but it will give you the result you want.

```
SET @rank = 0;

SELECT *
FROM
(
    select (@rank := @rank + 1) AS Rank,
    ProductKey, 
    count(1) as numberSold
    from A
    group by ProductKey 
    order by count(1) desc
) dt
WHERE dt.ProductKey = 'prod27';
```